# Groovy random password No such field found: field java.lang.String size

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

What I'm running in order to create a random password with alphanumeric and special characters

```
randomPasswordCreation = random_password_creation(14)
println "Random pass: $randomPasswordCreation"

def random_password_creation(pass_length ){
  def special = ['!','@','#','$','%','&'] 
  def pool = ['a'..'z','A'..'Z',0..9,'_'].flatten().plus(special);
  Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

  def passChars = (0..pass_length - 1).collect { pool[rand.nextInt(pool.size)] };
  def specialChar = special[rand.nextInt(special.size)]
  passChars[rand.nextInt(passChars.size)] = specialChar
  def PASSWORD = passChars.join();
  return PASSWORD
}
```

What I receive as error

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String size
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:426)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:410)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.collect(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:3170)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.collect(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:3140)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1922)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems with the code you have shown:

1. You access `size` as it was a field, but it is a method, so it should be `size()` instead.
2. The `passChars.join()` is missing a separator argument, e.g. `''` for an empty string.

Based on the error stack trace, I assume you are running this code as a part of a Jenkins Pipeline. Keep in mind, that Jenkins executes Groovy in a more restrictive way. For instance, while the regular dynamic Groovy can handle things like `.size` instead of `.size()`, the WorkflowScript executor requires that the Groovy code is free from such mistakes.

Comment: Seems depending on your groovy version, you can call the `join()` method without arguments as well...contrary to what the docs tell us if I read the tea leaves correctly from my phone.